# fields_for helper not working in .js.rjs after convert from js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't get working this code, after convert from Rails 3.0 (prototype) .js.rjs file to Rails 4 (jQuery) .js.erb

The line `$("#subcategory_0").html("<p>prova2</p>");` is never executed

Old File, .js.rjs:

```
if @subcategories
    @expense=Expense.new
    new_expense_detail=@expense.expense_details.build
    form_for(@expense) do |f| 
        f.fields_for(:expense_details,new_expense_detail,:child_index=>@child_index) do |builder|
            page.replace_html "subcategory_#{@child_index}", :partial => "expenses/subcategory", :locals=>{:f=>builder,:child_index=>@child_index}
        end
    end
end
```

Now, after convert to JQuery (and Rails 4), "prova1" is displayed, but "prova2" not.
And, I don't know why

```
 $("#subcategory_0").html("<p>prova1</p>");
<%if @subcategories %>
  <%@expense=Expense.new%>
  <%new_expense_detail=@expense.expense_details.build%>
  <%form_for(@expense) do |f| %>

    <%f.fields_for(:expense_details,new_expense_detail,:child_index=>@child_index) do |builder|%>

      // --- This line is not executed --- //
      $("#subcategory_0").html("<p>prova2</p>");

    <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Thanks a lot, I guess that's a silly question, but can't found js.erb file examples.
(Sorry my English)

Comment: Before `form_for` and `f.fields_for` it should be `<%=` instead of `<%`, I think.

Comment: I had already tried, and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a drastical solution for my problem

all these helpers (form_for and fields_for) were there to reproduce the collecion_select and all its properties, model and its one to many relationship. without to hardcode the select object name... etc

Now I **only** change the select options via javascript (jQuery) and options_from_collection_for_select

```
<%if @subcategories %>

  <% options=options_from_collection_for_select(@subcategories, :id, :name )  %>

  $("#expense_expense_details_attributes_<%=@child_index%>_subcategory_id").empty();
  $("#expense_expense_details_attributes_<%=@child_index%>_subcategory_id").append("<%=j options%>");

<%end%>
```

eventhough I don't like this: `expense_expense_details_attributes_<%=@child_index%>_subcategory_id`

Answer (score 0):

Use a instance variable within fields_for block, and pass it to the partial: --> `@builder`

in js.erb

```
<%
  @expense=Expense.new
  new_expense_detail=@expense.expense_details.build
  form_for(@expense) do |f| 
    f.fields_for(:expense_details,new_expense_detail,:child_index=>@child_index) do |builder| 
      @builder=builder # <<--- New line compared js.rjs
    end
  end
%>

$("#cost_center_group_<%=@child_index%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'select_costcenter', locals: {f: @builder,child_index: @child_index}))%>");
```